# Command line compilation Xtend file has Error The method from the type refers missing object

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, rcp, xtend

Why is there no problem compiling xtend code using eclipse? Compiling from the command line will result in an error？

```
java -cp .\lib\* org.eclipse.xtend.core.compiler.batch.Main -d .\bin -useCurrentClassLoader -encoding UTF-8 .\ara-configruator\com.ap.diag .\ara-configurator\com.ap.module .\ara-configurator\com.ap.service
```

> 0 [main] ERROR org.eclipse.xtend.core.compiler.batch.XtendBatchCompiler -
> Error: X_Typed_Data_Identifier_h.xtend - D:\AP_git\antTest\ara-configurator\com.ap.diag\src\com\ap\generator_V2\X_Typed_Data_Identifier_h.xtend
> 101: The method getDiagReadDidList() from the type InforOfArxml refers to the missing type Object

Confirmed the existence of the method in `InforOfArxml`, but still reported an error.

Comment: Maybe this is related: https://github.com/eclipse/xtext-xtend/issues/576 - As mentioned in the second comment of that issue, it could mean that the method's return type could not be found, e.g. if the method returns a type from a third-party library that is not in the classpath